# Website take to much time to load

Tags: html

My website is take too much time to load.
My server capacity is 500 MB, and i use only 35mb.

even i reduce file size of image, also compress images, less use external files.
But can't find the exact problem,
can anyone help..

My Website - www.swapneelpatidar.com

Comment: sorry for  repeat content

Answer (score 0):

Your portfolio images are taking time. Reduce size of that and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your website images are .PNG and that makes the size really big (1.3mb). This requires a lot of resources from the server. Change them to .jpg and it will be much faster!

[image]

Comment: how can i test as you could

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a problem with the file size, the problem is with the server response time I tested the loading time of the site files and I saw it took some over a second just to respond and start the download.

1. check with the hosting service that they don't limit the speed of the website.
2. try a different hosting service.